# How to break out to the parent tag and get the innerHTML of the next tag with javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I would like to get the value "450" next to the strong tag with "Total:" in it. I cant seem to identify this. I've tried using parentNode etc and I cannot find the right combination. Would be grate

Here is a jsfiddle of it - https://jsfiddle.net/smduy1w3/

```
<tfoot>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="text-right"><strong>Sub-Total:</strong></td>
    <td class="text-right">£450.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="text-right"><strong>Total:</strong></td>
    <td class="text-right">£450.00</td>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
```

```
var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName("strong");
var searchText = "Total:";
var found;

for (var i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++) {
  if (aTags[i].textContent == searchText) {
    found = aTags[i];console.log(found.previousNode);
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can check my solution. I've just searched for the element with `strong` tag with the text "Total" and then find out the `next sibling using nextSibling` and that did the work for me.

```js
const tds = [...document.querySelectorAll("td.text-right")];

const selected = tds.find((td) => td.innerHTML === `<strong>Total:</strong>`);
let nextSibling = selected.nextSibling;


while (nextSibling && nextSibling.nodeType !== 1) {
  nextSibling = nextSibling.nextSibling;
}
console.log(nextSibling.innerText.substr(1));
```

```html
<table>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4" class="text-right"><strong>Sub-Total:</strong></td>
          <td class="text-right">£450.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4" class="text-right"><strong>Total:</strong></td>
          <td class="text-right">£450.00</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have a couple of problems with your code:

First, for some reason, you need to wrap your html inside a `<table>` tag, or else the html isn't properly parsed.

Second, the search anchor `<strong>Total:</strong>` is a child node of its parent node `<td>` and the target `<td class="text-right">£450.00</td>` is a sibling of that parent, not the way you had it in your code.

So, assuming your html is fixed, you need to change

```
found = aTags[i];
console.log(found.previousNode);
```

to

```
found = aTags[i];
console.log(found.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling.textContent);
```

Second, I would argue that using xpath is a cleaner way of reaching your target; something along these lines:

```
target = document.evaluate( './/table//tr/td[strong[.="Total:"]]/following-sibling::td' ,document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null );

for (var i = 0; i < target.snapshotLength; i++) {
     price = target.snapshotItem (i);
     console.log(price.textContent);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName("strong");
var searchText = "Total:";
var found;

for (var i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++) {


  if(aTags[i].textContent.includes(searchText)){
    //console.log(aTags[i].textContent);
    found = aTags[i].nextSibling.textContent;
    console.log(found);
  }
}
```

```html
<tfoot>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="text-right"><strong>Sub-Total:</strong></td>
    <td class="text-right">£450.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="text-right"><strong>Total:</strong></td>
    <td class="text-right">£450.00</td>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
```